# Vlookup/ Match function in R for continuous column in R

Tags: r, match, vlookup

I have a 2 dataframe.
df1:

```
Dis1_SubDIs1_Village1       Dis2_SubDIs1_Village1   Dis1_SubDIs2_Village1
JODHPUR|JODHPUR|JODHPUR     |JODHPUR|JODHPUR        JODHPUR||JODHPUR
JHUNJHUNUN|JHUNJHUNUN|BARI  |JHUNJHUNUN|BARI        JHUNJHUNUN|BARI|BARI
BUNDI|HINDOLI|BUNDI         |HINDOLI|BUNDI          BUNDI|BUNDI|BUNDI
SIROHI|SIROHI|SIROHI        |SIROHI|SIROHI          SIROHI||SIROHI
ALWAR|ALWAR|BASAI           |ALWAR|BASAI            ALWAR||BASAI
BHARATPUR|BHARATPUR|SEEKRI  |BHARATPUR|SEEKRI       BHARATPUR||SEEKRI
```

and second data,
df2 :

```
High
|BHARATPUR|SEEKRI
BUNDI|HINDOLI|BUNDI
SIROHI||SIROHI
CHURU|TARANAGAR|DABRI CHHOTI
```

Now, I want to apply vloook/match in df1 with respect to df2 column. The same we do in excel.
If exact matches are there, give me the match, else 0.

I tried making the function in R 
For match

```
for(i in names(df1)){
  match_vector = match(df_final[,i], df$High, incomparables = NA)

  df1$High = df2$High[match_vector]

}
```

but getting an error. It's showing only for the last column and replacing the value of other column.

For vlookup:

```
func_vlook = function(a){
  for(i in 1:ncol(a)) {
    lookup_df = vlookup_df(lookup_value = i, 
                   dict = df2,
                   lookup_column = 1)

  }

  return(lookup_df)

}

lookup_df <- func_vlook(a = df1)
```

Still getting an error.

My final Output should be like the below attached with df file:

```
Dis1_SubDIs1_Village1_M1   Dis2_SubDIs1_Village1_M2   Dis1_SubDIs2_Village1_M3
NA                         NA                             NA
NA                         NA                             NA
BUNDI|HINDOLI|BUNDI        NA                             NA
NA                         SIROHI||SIROHI              SIROHI||SIROHI
NA                         NA                             NA
NA                         NA                          |BHARATPUR|SEEKRI
```

for the N no. of columns, there should be N no. of columns with match
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any loops with this one - `apply` and `match` should work fine. `apply` will iterate over as many columns you have, so the output will have the same number of columns as the input. In your example, `apply` will simplify to produce a matrix.

```
apply(X = df1, 
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = function(x) df2$High[match(x, df2$High)])
```

If you need a dataframe as the output, then wrap the code below in as.data.frame()

```
as.data.frame(apply(X = df1, 
      MARGIN = 2,
      FUN = function(x) df2$High[match(x, df2$High)]))
```

Comment: :: Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. If the answer was correct, can you accept it, so that it can closed?